# Error SQL71627 SQL Server bacpac migrate to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I got this error in deploying my database from PC to Azure with Windows 10 SQL Server 2O17 Management Studio task, this was because I still had a user with Windows Authentication in my database. I had to delete the user in order to have only users with SQL Server authentication (user/password)

Also this process is not compatible with SQL Server 2017 database, I had to get back to 2014, Azure is compatible up to 2016 (paper)

This question here for reference as I did not find any info on the 'net.

Best regards

Un ou plusieurs éléments non pris en charge ont été trouvés dans le schéma utilisé dans le cadre d'un package de données.
Error SQL71627 : La propriété AuthenticationType de l'élément Utilisateur: [PCVM\Dominique] est définie sur une valeur qui n'est pas prise en charge dans Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71627 : La propriété IsMappedToWindowsLogin de l'élément Connexion: [PCVM\Dominique] est définie sur une valeur qui n'est pas prise en charge dans Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Delete users except these four users (dbo - guest - INFORMATION_SCHEMA - sys)

Databases -> your database -> Security -> Users

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the specified user which is located at database->Security node.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't delete the users, but this MS tool worked perfectly. I was able to migrate both the schema and the data with it without any issues.

MS [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database) (DMA)

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options here. First is to use Visual Studio to generate DACPAC in order to help resolve the error. But using VS won't help to migrate data, it will help you to fix only the schema. Then you have to do import or export process yourself to new schema. 
The second option is to use SQL Azure Migration Wizard to resolve the error.